# Filter out substring columns within [..] in Shell using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to filter out only the specific portions within [..] from a specific IO, using `awk`. But, I am not getting the desired output.

```
Workflow: [wf_Mod1_INTERFACE_A] version [11]. Workflow run status: [Scheduled] Schedule time: [Mon Nov 16 16:00:00 2015]
Workflow: [wf_exec1_INTERFACE_A] version [6]. Workflow run status: [Scheduled] Schedule time: [Mon Nov 16 15:00:00 2015]
```

I am looking for an output using `awk`, which will return in 3 separate columns delimited by tab:

```
wf_Mod1_INTERFACE_A Scheduled Mon Nov 16 16:00:00 2015
wf_exec1_INTERFACE_A Scheduled Mon Nov 16 15:00:00 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F"[][]" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $2,$6, $8, $10, $14, $16}' inputFile
```

This will output six tab-separated columns with the desired information from your input.
To combine two or more columns in the above output, replace `,` by `" "`. This will replace a tab by a single blank (of course, you can use any string you want: `","`, `":"`, ...), e.g.

```
awk -F"[][]" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $2, $6" "$8, $10, $14" "$16}' inputFile
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your help Knorr :)